# Showing that $|x-y| \leq |x| +|y|$ for $x.y \in \mathbb{R}$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, proof-verification

I know from intuition that $|x-y| \leq |x| +|y|$ for $x.y \in \mathbb{R}$. The way I would prove it is to use the triangle inequality:

$|x-y| = |x+(-y)| \leq |x| +|-y| = |x|+|y|$ for $x.y \in \mathbb{R}$. Would this proof be correct? Thanks!

Comment: I'd prove it like that too.

Comment: Your proof is correct. You can also show that $x-y\le |x|+|y|$ and $-(x-y)=y-x\le |x|+|y|.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also prove by noting that 
$$ |x-y|^2 = (x-y)^2 = x^2+y^2-2xy \\
\leq x^2+y^2 + 2|x||y| = (|x|+|y|)^2.$$